# How to get files type with php

Tags: php

I Want a solution to how to get files type with php .
example :
 if I upload a rar files or zip files or csv  files is save in database application/octet stream .
please help me .

Comment: You can use the file extension to see the filetype. Just explode on the last dot. You could run a function to validate the extension but I think you only need to extension in this case

Comment: Extension means exactly nothing @BartScheffer and should never be used for this

Comment: Seems I misunderstood the question then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file_name = 'whatever.zip';
$file_types = array("zip" => "Application/Octet-Stream");
$file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $file_types[$file_extension]; // displays Application/Octet-Stream
```

Comment: `$file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks, I had never heard of that function before. Editing my answer.

Comment: Your welcome. The extra ' was a mistake from my part, but seem to have copied it

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, I just saw the syntax error. digging into the function more, should be fun. :P

Comment: that's not work is stay show octet stream